# Creating a location wise search in Drupal 6 using Views and CCK

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

How Can i create a search for the CCK fields in Drupal? Currently using a Finder Module is giving some error. If there is some other way kindly help me with it . Also .. is it possible to have a drop down for the Location Module fields which are visible on the Nodes? Since if  I use use them for search then in the search the "ABC" and "abc" are treated as 2 separate locations.

Also is there some way in which I can have the exposed filters as Drop Down?

Kindly help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted the problem by simply using Views and and then exposing its filters. To ensure that i have a drop down in the search block i used the "Allowed Values" option while exposing the filter.

To see it in action check. : http://naplesres.designbracket.com/ 
the Find Local Coupons Block on this page.